# how to add range to the secondary_y axis in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I want to create a graph where I want to add range to the secondary y-axis. The graph which I have right now is like this.
[image]

The code for this graph is like this:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import logging

fileName = 'solar data.xlsx'
app = xw.App(visible=False)
try:
    wb = app.books.open(fileName)
    sheet = wb.sheets[4]
    lastCell = sheet.range('A1').end('down').last_cell.row

    solarOne = sheet.range('B2:B'+ str(lastCell)).value
    bessOne = sheet.range('D2:D'+ str(lastCell)).value
    socOne = sheet.range('E2:E'+ str(lastCell)).value
    solarOne_Plus_bessOne = [i+j for i,j in zip(solarOne,bessOne)]

    # solarTwo = sheet.range('F2:F' + str(lastCell)).value
    # bessTwo = sheet.range('H2:H' + str(lastCell)).value
    # socTwo = sheet.range('I2:I' + str(lastCell)).value
    # solarTwo_Plus_bessTwo = [i + j for i, j in zip(solarTwo, bessTwo)]


except Exception as e:
    logging.exception("Something awful happened!")
    print(e)
finally:
    app.quit()
    app.kill()


fig = go.Figure()
projectTime = pd.date_range("2020-10-01 00:00:00", "2020-10-01 23:59:00", freq="1T")

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x =  projectTime, y =  solarOne, name = 'Solar', fill='tozeroy', line=dict(width=0.5, color='rgb(255,167,0)')), secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x =  projectTime, y =  bessOne, name = 'Storage', fill='tozeroy', line=dict(width=0.5, color='rgb(43, 201, 34)')), secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x =  projectTime, y =  socOne, name = 'SoC', fill='tozeroy', line=dict(width=0.5, color='rgb(250, 67, 67)')), secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x =  projectTime, y =  solarOne_Plus_bessOne, name = 'Solar + BESS', fill='tozeroy',), secondary_y=False)

# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Solar with 0.5MW  0.5Hour storage"
)

# Set x-axis title
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Time")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Dispatch(MW) and SoC(MWh)")

pyo.plot(fig, filename='Solar with 0.5MW 0.5Hour storage example 1.html')
```

I have tried to add `layout_yaxis_range=[-0.6, 0.7]` in secondary y-axis but it throws an error

```
TypeError: add_trace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'layout_yaxis_range'
```

I want this secondary y-axis with the same x-axis. Can anyone please help?

Comment: `fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(range=[-0.6,0.7]))` Why don't you try this?

Comment: can we set this automatically? I mean as you can see in the graph the x-axis for the secondary y-axis is completely different from the primary axis. That's the whole reason why I wanted to adjust the range of the secondary y-axis so that it can match with the primary axis.

Comment: `fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(range=[y1.min(),y1max()]))`You can set the minimum and maximum values for the first y-axis.

Comment: it is saying that y1 is not defined.

Comment: Is y1 just shown as an example, or is this what it actually is? `fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(range=[solarOne.min(),solarOnemax()]))`

Comment: What about for specifying the secondary y-axis range in a subplot? `yaxis2=dict(range=[..., ...])` works but only for the subplot in (1, 1)...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in similar cases:

```
fig.update_yaxes(range=[-0.6, 0.7], secondary_y=True)
```